# Create a dictionary by parsing text in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have following data in my log file.

```
Element1
data1
data2
data3
Element2
data1
data4
data6
Element3
data9
data3
data5
....
```

and so on.

I want to create a dictionary by parsing through this file:

```
Dictionary (int, List (( string)) <br/>
```

where int is number from Element1 --> 1, Element2 --> 2, whereas the data that follows Element1 is included in the List.

So,

For Element1, `Dictionary<1, List<<string>>` will include the list `{ data1, data2, data3 }`

For Element2, `Dictionary<2, List<<string>>` will include the list `{ data1, data4, data6 }`

...and so on.

I did some programming like

```
string lines [ ] = File.ReadAllLines ( path );
foreach ( string s in lines )
{
    // processing lines to find element and then record each line after
    // till I find another element or EOL.
}
```

I would like to convert this into a LINQ statement, but I am not able to figure out the answer. I tried to go over the LINQ command `TakeWhile` but still not able to get the solution.

Comment: how do you differentiate between the keys and the values of the dictionary? Is it always triplets, or small caps or something else? Wouldn't you want to take a more structured file format?

Comment: Why do you think LINQ will be better? I can't think about any standard LINQ method that would help here.

Comment: Does the data1, data2, data3, etc... fields have the potential to contain the word `Element` ?

Comment: @FeistyMango No data1,data2, etc will not contain Element word.

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov Keys will be the value on int from last encountered eg Element1 will have key as 1, element9 will have key as 9, so basically parsing int from element*. <br/> Values will be the list of string with all those data1,data2, etc recorded after Element[i] till next encountered Element[i+1].

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with LINQ, and even if you can, it would be no more readable or effective than writing a method to do it.

```
private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<string, string, string>>> ReadAll(string path)
{ // you might want some more concrete types here, but this will help turn it into a dictionary just as well as anything else.

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        string title;

        while ((title = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string data1 = reader.ReadLine();
            string data2 = reader.ReadLine();
            string data3 = reader.ReadLine();

            yield return new KeyValuePair<string, Tuple<string, string, string>>(title, new Tuple<string, string, string>(data1, data2, data3));
        }
    }
}
```

You still get all the benefits of `IEnumerable<T>`, but this way will help you maintain and expand it if need be.

You can build you dictionary with a simple:

```
return ReadAll(path).ToDictionary(c => c.Key, c => c.Value);
```

But yeah, even if you *could* do this with LINQ, this is what it'd be doing under the covers anyway. LINQ is framework-level syntactic sugar and does not inherently do anything to better your code, aside from making it easier to write and more readable. But in this case, I think being explicit with your method is more readable. Particularly since parsing the file is *probably* a relatively significant operation in the scheme of things.